# is this set a regular surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I'm reading "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces of Manfredo Docarmo" I'm doing  the exercises of the chapter 2. Here is the definition of regular surface that we are following: [image]

I have problems with this exercise: [image]

Is with the first part, I think that it's not true that it's a regular surface (the second it is). I don't know how to prove that something is not a regular surface.

Comment: What happens if you take the point $p$ on the boundary of the unitary disc? How would you construct the homeomorphism?

Answer (score 2):

It is because in any neighborhood of a boundary point none of the orthogonal projections to the coordinate plane give a parametrization. This is a proposition in that section,and is often used to show that something is not a manifold.

Comment: What about $f(x,y) = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there exists a chart X from an open set U of **R^2** to a part of a surface for every point on the disc. And as X is a homeomorphism onto its image, the set X(U) is open in the surface, i.e., in the induced topology inherited from **R^3**. But, the given set is a closed disc of radius 1 and hence compact and hence for every open cover of the disc, there is a finite subcover. Clearly, union of all the charts over all the points on the disc covers the disc. And since there is a finite subcover, let X(U1), X(U2),....,X(Un) be the finite subcover. That means union of these n open sets contains the disc and on the other hand, the disc contains all these open sets and all individually are contained in the disc. And hence union of all these open sets is exactly equal to the disc, but the union is open whereas the disc is closed. Hence, the closed disc is not a regular surface.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).